# ¿Cómo dar formato a las palabras con jxl java?

Tags: java

Estoy creando un reporte con la librería jxl de java, y agrego el contenido de las celdas de la siguiente manera:

```
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(arial48pt);
cellFormat.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.THIN);
cellFormat.setWrap(true);
Label texto;
SolicitudClienteInterFlujo scif = new SolicitudClienteInterFlujoDAO().datosReporteSolicitud(idSolicitudClientInteFlujo);
texto = new Label(0, 2, "texto común",cellFormat);
```

Y quería saber si hay alguna manera de formatear solamente una palabra en negrilla así:

texto **común** dentro de la misma celda claro está.

Answer (score 2):

De acuerdo con la [lista de Preguntas Frecuentes, *FAQ*](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/) (véase específicamente *Does JXL support feature XXXXXX?*), Java Excel API aún no soporta texto enriquecido en las celdas.

No obstante, dicho sea de paso, [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) (otra librería que también permite la lectura y escritura de hojas de cálculo) sí lo soporta a través de la clase [`HSSFRichTextString`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html) o de la clase [`XSSFRichTextString`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html). Ejemplo:

```
Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
RichTextString rt = new XSSFRichTextString("texto común");
Font font = wb.createFont();
font.setBoldWeight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
rt.applyFont(6, 10, font);
cell.setCellValue(rt);
```